# how to use Context for class Component in other module in React js

Tags: reactjs

when i use context in Reactjs ,by using hooks I just can use 'useContext' for function component in other module , but I want to use it for -->  class component  <-- in other module but i cant do it, and in browser console i see this error: ==>> ((

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MyContext' before initialization
Module.MyContext
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:12:101
Module../src/news.js
F:/0 React Js project/my-appfirst-app/src/news.js:21
```

))

do we have any way to use class component in other module?

these are my codes

parent commponent:

```
import React,{createContext,Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Roots from './news'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


export let MyContext=createContext();

class Show extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <MyContext.Provider value={{name:'ali',family:'mohammady',done:'false'}} >
        <div className='container-main'>
          <Roots />
        </div>
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Show />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and this child module:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {MyContext} from './index'

class Roots extends Component{
  static  contextType = MyContext;
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <p>{console.log(this.context)}</p>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Roots;
```

I wonder how to work this codes if i put child component in parent component !!??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export then import the consumer from the context to use it like that

```
export let MyContext=createContext();
export const MyContextConsumer = MyContext.Consumer
```

Then import that consumer and use it

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { MyContextConsumer } from './index'

class Roots extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <MyContextConsumer>
        {value => <p>{console.log(value)}</p>}
      </MyContextConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@topched

thanks for your help
your answer is very helpful for me but the console show the error again and then I did a few changes on your code and it runs without error.

when I use bottom script in index.js , i get error but i created a new file with the name context.js and put bottom script in it , the codes run without error

```
export let MyContext=createContext();
export const MyContextConsumer = MyContext.Consumer
```

Comment: I dont quite follow what you are saying but it sounds like its working so thats great